# SVM is very slow when training classifier on big number of classes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, svm

I'm trying to train an SVM classifier on big number of items and classes, which becomes really, really slow.

First of all, I've extracted a feature set from my data, to be specific 512 features overall and put it in numpy array. There are 13k items in this array. It looks like that:

```
>>print(type(X_train))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>print(X_train)
[[ 0.01988654 -0.02607637  0.04691431 ...  0.11521499  0.03433102
  0.01791015]
[-0.00058317  0.05720023  0.03854145 ...  0.07057668  0.09192026
  0.01479562]
[ 0.01506544  0.05616265  0.01514515 ...  0.04981219  0.05810429
  0.00232013]
...
```

Also, there are ~4k of different classes:

```
>> print(type(labels))
<class 'list'>
>> print(labels)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, ... ]
```

And here is the classifier:

```
import pickle
from thundersvmScikit import SVC

FILENAME = 'dataset.pickle'

with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as infile:
    (X_train, labels) = pickle.load(infile)

clf = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
clf.fit(X_train, labels)
```

After ~90 hours has passed (and I'm using GPU implementation of sci-learn kit in a form of thundersvm) fit operation is still running. Taking into account that it is a pretty small dataset in my case I definitely need something more efficient, but I don't seem to have any good success with that. For example, I've tried this type of Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=512, units=100, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=n_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, labels, epochs=500, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True)
```

I end up with pretty good accuracy during the training stage:

```
Epoch 500/500
11988/11988 [==============================] - 1s 111us/step - loss: 2.1398 - acc: 0.8972 - val_loss: 9.5077 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

However, during the actual testing even on the data that was present in the training dataset I got extremely low accuracy, predicting basically random classes:

```
Predictions (best probabilities):
  0  class710015: 0.008
  1  class715573: 0.007
  2  class726619: 0.006
  3  class726619: 0.010
  4  class720439: 0.007
Accuracy: 0.000
```

Could you, please, point me in the right direction with this? Should I adjust SVM approach somehow or should I switch to custom Keras model for  this type of a problem? If yes, what is the possible problem with my model?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT use that SVC implementation if it relies on the scikit-learn implementation of multiclass SVC. In the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) it states "The multiclass support is handled according to a one-vs-one scheme." Meaning you train one classifier for every pair of classes, i.e. ~ 2^4k classifiers are being trained. You could use anything listed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) under "Inherently multiclass"

Also your Keras implementation probably needs another layer. I'm assuming the output layer has 1 neuron for each class, in which case you'd want to use categorical crossentropy and softmax activation, as well as one hot encoding.

I'm assuming right now that all of your examples only have one class label.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. By the way, you are correct in your assumption that my examples have only one class label. So, as far as I understood I should get rid of SVM (SVC) implementation.

Comment: Also, it is actually recommended to use binary cross entropy loss function and sigmoid activation function for multi class classification, so the problem is not in this piece of the model for sure.

Comment: Can you give me a citation for that @none32 ?

Comment: Sure. I found this information there: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2166#issuecomment-204746792

Comment: That's not what you're saying here I believe. In almost all neural network settings you should 1 hot encode your classes. In this setting, they are saying if you are doing multilabel classification then binary cross-entropy is correct. You previously said each of your examples has 1 label, therefore, it is not multilabel, and therefore it should be 1 hot encoded with categorical cross entropy.

Comment: My bad. Seems that you are correct here. I've mixed up multi-class and multi-label classification.

Answer (score 2):

SVM is most natural for binary classification. For multiclass, scikit-learn uses one-versus-one to combine O(K^2) binary classifiers (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), with K the number of classes. So, the running time is proportional to K^2, or in your case, 16 million. This is the reason why it is so slow.

You should either reduce the number of classes, or switch to other models such as neural networks or decision trees.

P.S: scikit-learn also has one-vs-all approach for SVM (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), which is O(K). You could also try this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As I stated, I've tried to utilize Keras for neural networks for this classification problem, experimented with different model configurations quite a bit, but still getting no good results. Could you, please, point me in the write direction in terms of models structure for my problem?

Comment: You cannot expect a very good accuracy with so many classes. Usually, a large number of classes require a large deep neural network and fairly a large amount of training time. You can check some papers running on CIFAR-100 (there should be many) to see the state-of-the-art. I cannot tell you the right structure because you haven't given any illustration on the problem.