# How to use ThunderSVM (GPU mode) on Pycharm in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, svm, libsvm

I followed the instructor on the official github of ThunderSVM and installed it for Windows. I can run ThuderSVM in git-bash CLI. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522208/svm-is-very-slow-when-training-classifier-on-big-number-of-classes) shows that we can add ThunderSVM into Keras, how about Pycharm? My question is how to run ThunderSVM on Pycharm.

In the folder thundersvm/build/lib: I have thundersvm.exp, thundersvm.lib, thundersvm-train.exp, thundersvm-train.lib, thundersvm-predict.exp, and thundersvm-predict.lib files.

I installed Pycharm on Windows 10 and interpreted it using python 3.6 through Anaconda. My GPU is RTX 2070.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to my question.

1. Cloning ThunderSVM and went to C:\Users\user-name\thundersvm\python\thundersvm
2. Copying all files in here and post them in a new folder in Pycharmproject.
3. Opening Pycharm and reconfigure Project Interpreter in File/Settings.

I can run ThunderSVM in Pycharm right now. However, I realize that the built-in SVM of sklearn is faster than ThunderSVM in my case (many different small training data = many times to train SVM, and I have to write down the model in each time training). I tried SVM of tensorflow: tf.contrib.learn.SVM also and received the same result (tensorflow is faster than ThunderSVM but less accuracy).